# Counting instances of same field entry

Tags: filemaker

I have a Filemaker table with multiple entries in `fieldA`, how can I set `fieldB` to count the number of occurrences of the corresponding number of records which have the same value in `fieldA`.

For example, if `fieldA` is a;b;b;c I want `fieldB` to read 1;2;2;1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to make a self-relationship from the table to another occurrence of the same table by `fieldA`. Then `fieldB` can be like `Count( sameFieldA::fieldA )`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a recursive custom function which you pass the fieldA contents in to.

It takes as parameters:

- the text being parsed
- the current position being parsed (starting at 1)
- the output text being built

grab the fieldA value (e.g. "a") at the supplied position, then [count the number of occurrences](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/func_ref3.33.73.html#1031282) of "a" in the text being parsed. Append this to the output text, then if there are more values to process, call the recursive function again, with an incremented position, returning the result. Otherwise, return the output text.